# Porque é que o sinal trema foi removido?

Tags: acordo-ortográfico, acentuação

De acordo com o artigo da Wikipédia sobre este sinal, [o trema](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trema) foi [removido](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1945#Base_XXVII), com a excepção de palavras derivadas de nomes próprios estrangeiros (por exemplo, *mülleriano*, de *Müller*).

Segundo a minha perceção, este sinal deveria ser usado em palavras como 'pinguim' e 'linguista', para indicar a pronúncia do 'u' nos grupos 'gua', 'gue', 'gui', entre outros.

A remoção deste sinal parece-me apenas introduzir ainda mais excepções, que, acho, deveriam ser evitadas. Há algum benefício com a remoção deste sinal?

Comment: No português europeu acho que nunca vi o trema a ser utilizado.

Comment: Eu também não, mas acho que deveria. E segundo o artigo da wikipedia, era usado até 1945.

Comment: Porque era muito chato apertar shift + 6. Brincadeira...

Comment: Tu diz exclusivamente no português brasileiro, no europeu ou num geral?

Comment: Dos livros que li e aulas que fiz, aprendi escrever *tranqüilo*, *conseqüência*, e *averigüe*. Pelo jeito aprendi demais (ou de livros velhíssimos!)

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar "Velhíssimos". Só significa que eram de antes de 1990, acho. De qualquer modo, essa forma faz mais sentido

Comment: a remoção da trema criou um problema para os professores de lingua portuguesa, como explicar que Linguiça, o (gui) se pronuncia diferente Guia (gui).

Comment: @AFetter os professores de português já devem estar acostumados.. essa será só mais uma das incoerências que eles deverão saber explicar, exemplo: "cedo" -> "selo"; "xadrez" -> "chafariz"; "gelo" -> "jeito"; "texto" -> "misto"

Comment: @Math, desculpa, mas no exemplo que eu dei, se escreve exatamente da mesma forma. Tornando para o aluno mais dificil a compreensao. Como acontece como voce disse muitas vezes na lingua portuguesa. Bem lembrado.

Comment: @AFetter sim, no seu exemplo se escreve da mesma forma e se pronuncia diferente, nos exemplo que eu dei se escreve diferente e se pronuncia da mesma forma. O que eu quis dizer é que já estamos forrados de inconsistências e o trabalho do professor de português não é simples já não é de hoje :)

Comment: Someone, não sei se o trema alguma vez teve uso generalizado em Portugal. Ele foi previsto pela primeira vez no acordo de 1943 e abolido logo de seguida no acordo de 1945. A lei de 1911 não previa o trema, mas permitia o uso do acento grave para a mesma função (*agùentar, freqùente*) quando conviesse ao ensino das crianças.

Comment: @AFetter, maior dor de cabeça é o **x**. Pensa nos valores dele em *taxa, taxi, máximo* e *exato!*

Answer (score 19):

Resposta [copiada da wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trema) (e por este motivo, esta resposta é wiki da comunidade):

> ## Em Portugal
>
> Portugal utilizava o trema da mesma forma que o Brasil até o advento do [Acordo Ortográfico de 1945](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1945), que suprimiu o trema na grafia de palavras vernáculas, reservando-o somente para palavras derivadas de nomes estrangeiros, como mülleriano (do antropônimo Müller).
>
> ## No Brasil
>
> De acordo com o [Formulário Ortográfico de 1943](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formul%C3%A1rio_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1943), o trema era usado no Brasil para assinalar que a letra u nas combinações que, qui, gue e gui, normalmente muda, deveria ser pronunciada e átona. **Exemplos**: qüinqüênio (pronuncia-se então "cuincuênio") e conseqüência (pronuncia-se então "consecuência"). Se for tônica dever-se-ia pôr um acento agudo, como em "averigúe" e "argúi".
>
> Até a alteração promovida pela [Lei 5.765/1971](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/Leis/L5765.htm), o trema tinha uma utilização adicional: marcar hiatos átonos, em palavras como gaüchismo. Na poesia, a palavra "saudade" podia ser grafada saüdade, quando se desejasse tornar essa palavra tetrassílaba em vez de apenas trissílaba.
>
> Mesmo antes da abolição do trema, com a entrada em vigor do [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990) no Brasil, o seu uso era controverso. Mesmo com os livros de língua portuguesa editados no Brasil determinando que o trema devesse ser grafado, era frequente (freqüente) que muitas pessoas não o usassem, seja por desconhecimento ou por considerar seu uso desnecessário. Certos órgãos de comunicação brasileiros e alguns canais de televisão se alternavam entre o emprego ou não do diacrítico, principalmente no uso da palavra seqüestro. O acordo ortográfico no Brasil só poderá passar a ser obrigatório em 2016, mas ainda existe um grande debate sobre os prós e contras do Novo Acordo, sofrendo muita rejeição, principalmente em Portugal (ver: [Manifesto em Defesa da Língua Portuguesa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifesto_em_Defesa_da_L%C3%ADngua_Portuguesa)).
>
> ## A abolição do trema
>
> O trema ainda não havia sido abolido porque a reforma ortográfica proposta desde o início dos anos 90 (ver os artigos [Língua portuguesa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_portuguesa) e [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990)) não havia entrado em vigor - o que fez com que o trema fosse obrigatório na teoria e facultativo na prática da versão brasileira da língua portuguesa, em função de muita gente já não o usar mais.
>
> O [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990), na Base XIV, determinou a inteira supressão do diacrítico em palavras portuguesas ou aportuguesadas, vetando inclusive seu uso em poesia, algo que no Brasil já fora abolido pela [Lei 5.765/1971](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/Leis/L5765.htm), que modificou o [Formulário Ortográfico de 1943](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formul%C3%A1rio_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1943).
>
> Com a entrada efetiva em vigor do Acordo em 2009, o uso do **trema** é facultativo no período de transição (2009-2012) e a partir dele fica restrito às palavras de origem estrangeira e seus derivados, tais como Müller e mülleriano, Hübner e hübneriano, sem contar o direito garantido na Base XXI, de manter a grafia original de nomes próprios, empresas e marcas com registro público.
>
> Essa indefinição só chegou ao fim no Brasil com a assinatura do [Decreto 6.583/2008](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_Ato2007-2010/2008/Decreto/D6583.htm), que em seu artigo 2°, parágrafo único, determina um prazo de transição entre 1° de janeiro de 2009 a 31 de dezembro de 2012. Portanto, a partir de 2013, o trema estará abolido oficialmente da ortografia do português brasileiro, respeitado o uso em palavras de origem estrangeira e derivados como "Müller" e "mülleriano".
>
> Ao chegar em dezembro de 2012, o trema pode ser usado até 1° de janeiro de 2016 após a vigência do Acordo Ortográfico ser adiada para 2016.

Answer (score 15):

São várias as inconsistências na ortografia portuguesa, como as letras diferentes produzindo os mesmo sons. Por exemplo:

- **ce**do → **se**lo; ambos se pronunciam "cê"
- **xa**drez → **ch**afariz; ambos se pronunciam /ʃ/
- **ge**lo → **je**ito; ambos se pronunciam /ʒ/
- e**x**clama → e**s**cama; ambos se pronunciam /s/

O trema era uma maneira de diferenciar a pronúncia ao se escrever "que", "gue", "qui" e "gui", mas ainda assim isso não resolvia todos os problemas, pois existem palavras que possuem duas pronúncias distintas consideradas como corretas, por exemplo:

- [liquidificador](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=liquidificador)
- [líquido](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=l%EDquido)
- [liquidação](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=liquida%E7%E3o)

Todas essas pode-se pronunciar tanto "qui" como "qwi", mas o mais comum (ao menos no Brasil) é pronunciar "qwi"; entretanto a escrita dessas palavras nunca fez uso do trema, tornando bem confuso a regra para se escrever corretamente usando ou não o trema.

Além do mais, o uso do trema já não era consenso entre os países lusófonos, sendo mais usado no Brasil. Com a vinda do acordo ortográfico e a unificação da grafia optou-se por retirá-lo ao invés de implementá-lo nos demais países, deixando a escrita mais simples e afetando apenas a forma de escrever dos brasileiros.

Nativos da língua estão acostumados a primeiro aprender a falar e somente depois a escrever, portanto, sua extinção tende a não afetar a pronúncia das palavras que perderam o trema e é possível que simplifique as coisas extinguindo a regra do uso de mais um diacrítico.

Fontes:
- [A Tribuna Mato Grosso - Mudanças ortográficas: necessárias, desnecessárias e tímidas?](http://www.atribunamt.com.br/2007/10/mudancas-ortograficas-necessarias-desnecessarias-e-timidas/)
- [Brasil Escola - TREMA – É HORA DE PARTIR!](http://www.brasilescola.com/acordo-ortografico/trema-e-hora-de-partir.htm)

Comment: Math devias explicar melhor em que ponto dos exemplos é que as letras diferentes produzem o mesmo som. Só por curiosidade eu nem sabia da existência do trema até começar a ver Alemão escrito.

Comment: @JorgeB. eu gostaria, mas eu não sei escrever aquelas coisas que vão entre barras `/`, tipo o nosso amigo ali em cima que escreveu "/pɪŋ.ˈgĩ/ e /pɪŋ.ˈgwĩ/". Foi por isso que eu criei essa pergunta: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/447/3 mas ela está pobre e mal formulada, então ainda não aprendi como fazer isso e não sei uma maneira simples de explicar a pronúncia dos sons :'(

Comment: @JorgeB. vou arriscar...

Comment: Eu acho que os exemplos de sonoridade dupla não são importantes. Também se pode dizer «ouro» e «oiro», ou «louro» e «loiro». Há exemplos de duas pronúncias e duas escritas possíveis. Da mesma forma, podia haver duas escritas possíveis para líquido/líqüido; não vejo problema ou incongruência nisto.

Comment: @ANeves eu expliquei que a trema era para diferenciar silabas que possuem pronúncias diferentes dependendo da palavra, por exemplo o "que" em "queijo" e em "cinquenta", daí eu mostrei exemplos que a pronuncia já era igual ao de palavras que se usa a trema, mas sem a necessidade dela. O fato dela possuir sonoridade dupla é uma confusão extra, mas o "qui" em "liquidificador" que faz o som de "qwi", pode mostrar que a trema realmente é irrelevante. Você acha que esses exemplos deveriam ser removidos? Ou de repente mudar a forma como escrevi? Para mim ainda me parecem relevantes.

Comment: `ainda assim isso não resolvia todos os problemas pois existem palavras que possuem duas pronúncias distintas consideradas como corretas` - eu acho que resolvia. Essas palavras teriam duas grafias possíveis: «líquido» e «líqüido». Da mesma forma que se pode escrever tanto «louro» como «loiro».

Comment: Bem visto que a supressão do trema não deverá afetar a pronúncia. De facto, em Portugal nunca se usou o trema, e os portugueses continuam a pronunciar [gwe] em *aguentar*, [gwi] em *arguir*, etc.

Comment: Os nativos da língua estão acostumados a falar as palavras mais comuns, mas e sobre as palavras mais raras, eruditas, ou científicas? Agüentar poderia ser escrito agntr que continuaria sendo agwentar, mas quinquênio, quiasma, quieira, quiangue, guianaíta? Sem falar que podemos desconfiar que algumas pronúncias duplas com u/ü podem ter surgido justamente pela ambigüidade da escrita em vez de serem pré-existentes. Vejam o caso de Guiana, que algumas pessoas pronunciam Ghiana porque não há nenhum indicativo que era pra ser "Gúy"ana. Esse é um caso pior porque não se trata de "gwi" mas de "guy".

Answer (score 5):

Pelo que pude entender numa breve pesquisa pelo Google, essa mudança, como provavelmente tantas outras do Novo Acordo Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa, foi estabelecida pela variedade de regras que havia no seu uso dentre os países que usam a Língua Portuguesa. Logo, na tentativa do Novo Acordo de unificar os países que tem o português como língua oficial, o sinal trema foi removido.

Comment: Por exemplo "pinguim" deveria se ler algo como /pɪŋ.ˈgĩ/, mas lê-se  /pɪŋ.ˈgwĩ/ como se o _u_ fosse aberto. Se tivesse o trema, seria óbvio que o _u_ não pertencia ao ditongo, mas assim cria-se uma excepção.

Comment: Fizeram isso para agradar os portugueses. Como muitas das palavras têm a dupla pronúncia, e como já não era obrigado a usar o sinal, resolveram acabar com ele. Mas as palavras que possuem apenas pronúncia com o 'gu' separado ficaram absurdas: linguiça é o grande exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Depois que tiraram o trema e outros acentos diacríticos, o português se tornou ridículo. Ele ou eles faz(em) a diferença nas palavras que usam as mesmas combinações de letras, especialmente os dígrafos gu e qu seguidos de e ou i para a correcta pronúncia das letras nas sílabas destas palavras. Sempre aprendi assim.

O italiano, idioma que dizem ser complexo na aprendizagem para eles mesmos e ainda mais para os estrangeiros devido à grande quantidade de consoantes duplas, utiliza vários dígrafos que raramente se confundem nas palavras, em contrapartida ao que acontece conosco.Vejamos:

1. perché (porque: ch com som de qu duro ou seco)
2. frequente (freqüente : qu com som de u pronunciado)
3. guerra (guerra: mas com o u pronunciado como se tivesse o trema)
4. ghiaccio (gelo: g seco ou duro como guitarra ou garagem)
5. agguato (gu com u pronunciado como em guardar; significado: armadilha;emboscada;surpresa inesperada e/ou desagradável)

Nas seqüências gue e gui a pronúncia é como se eles tivessem a diérese ou trema, com o u proferido.

Nos idiomas germânicos, em especial o alemão, a pronúncia da vogal u com o trema não há nada a que ver com a nossa dicção ou pronúncia. Ele faz pronunciar a letra u mais perto da vogal i (über - acima; superior: über alles: acima de tudo).Tal fenômeno chama-se metafonia.

No inglês, tal som pode ser representado nos dígrafos ee ou oo, como por exemplo, na palavra seen (i) ou soon (ü) visto e cedo, respectivamente.

Comment: Por que o português se tornou ridículo? Não entendi.

Comment: Acredito que todas as línguas tem inconsistências, português é só mais uma. Por que exemplo em inglês "bear" e "fear" tem pronuncias tão diferentes se na escrita são tão próximas? Ou ainda por que no inglês britânico se escreve "theatre" enquanto no americano se escreve "theater"?

Comment: Verdade. Sem mais nada a dizer.

Comment: Com certeza é que o trema deveria ser usado para evitar confusões lingüísticas.

Comment: Devido à esta coisa de o português ser pronunciado de um jeito, mas escrito de outro; ainda mais sendo geográfica a razão de a pronúncia ser mais aberta ou fechada. Por que devemos nós, brasileiros, adotar a mesma pronúncia de vogal fechada, enquanto a fazíamos aberta? Exemplos: idéia (BR); ideia:(PT: ê); carotenóide (BR)
       carotenoide (PT) 

O trema: lingüiça (BR); ambigüidade (BR)
 senão fica: lingiça; ambigidade

Comment: "lingiça; ambigidade" -- acho que estas grafias seriam lidas como "linjissa" e "ambijidade", não?

Answer (score 0):

Àqueles que dizem que os falantes já sabem por natureza quais palavras pronunciam-se ou não a letra U, discordo plenamente e trago algumas situações (aberrações lingüísticas) que ouço em meu quotidiano:

1. Distinguir / Extinguir (geralmente pronunciado com a letra U, o que não deveria acontecer, já que há um padrão para VERBOS no infinitivo terminados em GUIR, como Conseguir, Seguir, Prosseguir sem a pronúncia de tal letra).
2. Güiana Francesa (pronunciada por muitos como /Guiana/ sem a articulação da letra U).
3. Equino / Eqüino (vocábulos que especificam tipos de animais diferentes, mas que têm sido pronunciados igualmente. Eqüino é relativo aos eqüídios e cavalos, enquanto Equino refere-se a animais marinhos sésseis ou com movimentos lentos, como a Estrela-do-mar).
4. Qüinqüênio (pode se ouvir sendo articulado como /Quinqüênio/ e aí me pergunto: Que critério usar para a pronúncia em apenas no segundo ditongo?)

E NÃO! O Acordo Ortográfico não diz que a pronúncia de tais palavras com GUI/GUE/QUE/QUI fica a critério do falante. A base XIV do Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 afirma que, o trema é suprimido, mas a pronúncia não se altera.

Quanto aos estrangeiros que estão aprendendo o português, coitados, erram todas as palavras a toda hora.

São estes pequenos detalhes que destróem a riqueza da nossa querida língua. Logo, novas resoluções devem ser tomadas para mitigar tal problemática.

A perda do trema é realmente uma grande perda.

Comment: Isto faz-me lembrar o estilo de polémica que autores como o [Vasco Graça Moura](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasco_Gra%C3%A7a_Moura) e tantos outros usavam como pretexto para escrever bitaites nos jornais. Mas se o AO não fosse o pretexto outro encontravam pois alimentar polémicas e mandar bitaites é o que os polemistas fazem. Li alguma da produção escrita desses polemistas e fosse qual fosse a grafia achei-lhes sempre pouca substância.

Answer (score 0):

> A remoção deste sinal parece-me apenas introduzir **ainda mais excepções**, que, acho, deveriam ser evitadas.

De facto não, o trema nunca foi muito usado em Portugal nem nos outros países Lusófonos **excepto** no Brasil. Se não tivesse sido removido o trema pelo AO de 1990 (quando já era sabido que a internet viria em breve alterar o nosso quotidiano) estariamos agora -todos os falantes nativos e estrangeiros da língua de Camões- a ler e escrever com grafias divergentes, o que causaria enorme estranheza e faria destes gestos simples, uma constante fonte de diferenças.

Num dos exemplos dado noutra resposta:

> e**x**clama → e**s**cama; ambos se pronunciam /s/

O que importava na anterior grafia **não era a pronúncia mas manter os radicais eruditos importados do latim com a grafia original**, vejamos:

> excelso
>
> (latim e**x**celsus,-a, -um)

> escama
>
> (latim **s**quama, -ae)

Ao tornar a grafia dos radicais divergente com a etimologia e a diacrónia, para fazer a grafia seguir a pronúnica sincrónica, introduzimos um diferença não só em relação ao latim, mas também em relação ao inglês, ao francês, ao alemão e a todas as línguas que também importaram esses radicais... Por exemplo:

> A**c**to (pré AO 1990) > Ato (pós AO 1990)

### Agora vamos ver as outras línguas:

- Inglês

  > A**c**t, A**c**tion, A**c**tivity
- Francês

  > A**c**te, A**c**tion, A**c**tivité
- Alemão

  > A**k**t, A**k**tion, A**k**tivität
- Espanhol

  > A**c**to, A**cc**ión, A**c**tividad

Como podemos ver [até línguas que não são românicas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnguas_rom%C3%A2nicas) mantém os radicais mais próximos da grafia original do latim do que o português após o acordo ortográfico. O que de facto acontece é que ao perdermos essa semelhança estamos a divergir das restantes línguas (e das nossas origens) e estamos a isolar-nos na grafia o que vai causar maior estranheza ao encontrarmos línguas estrangeiras e quando esses estrangeiros encontrarem a nossa língua (e o mesmo pode ser dito, até, do uso do trema).

> [Trema](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trema)
>
> Em Portugal
>
> Portugal utilizava o trema da mesma forma que o Brasil até o advento do Acordo Ortográfico de 1945,

Esta história a mim coloca-me muitas dúvidas... Já li inúmeros livros do princípio do século 20 e século 19 nas edições originais e raramente vi tremas nas edições Portuguesas. O trema em Portugal já era muito pouco usado no vernáculo desde há muito. Talvez seja necessária escrever a história de como se foi usando o trema cada vez menos durante o século 19 em Portugal, e porquê no mesmo periodo o uso do trema parece ter continuado ou até ter-se intensificado no Brasil.

Answer (score -1):

Como saber se um "u" é átono e pronumciado ao escrever ou ao ler?

Afinal, a pronúncia é "portuGUÊS" ou "portuGWÊS" ? basta me explicar porque. (ou seria porqwe?)

Tiraram um acento, e criaram mais problemas do "qe" soluções. Estão "inglesando"(*) o portugwês, digo, portugês, digo, português (ufa!).

[(*) ou seja barbarizando uma língua romântica.]

"A criança aprende a falar antes de escrever..." (uma explicação "lógica" dada acima). É verdade... e depois, na escola, precisa engolir escritas iguais para fonéticas diferentes, ou fonéticas diferentes para escritas iguais; e tem de decorar, e se errar...

Continuando assim, em breve o grande desafio de crianças nas escolas lusófonas serão os "concursos de soletração" (como ocorre nos EEUU).

Comment: Olá, boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE. Obrigado pela contribuição, mas note que sua resposta é na verdade um comentário, pois não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação o bastante](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), você poderá deixar comentários em postagens.

Comment: Por qwe?, Qual a conseqência disso?
A desculpa de qwe as pessoas aprendem sua lingua nativa antes de aprender a escrever, e portanto sabem como a palavra e pronunciada e, assim, nao ha necssidade do trema e um contrasenso! Se for assim, nao ha necessidade de acento algum, como pohde ser visto acima. Todos nativos saberiam, pelo contexto, qwe armario e proparoxitona (e proparoxitona tambem), e que bau eh bauh e que Pele foi o melhor jogador do mundo (e Eusebio o segundo). E não haveria conseqe(u)encia nenhuma. Lingua nao e brinqwedo!!!

Comment: A observação sobre sua postagem não ser uma resposta remete ao formato desse site, que é: uma (e apenas uma) pergunta, seguida de resposta(s) (e apenas respostas), portanto bem diferente de um fórum de discussões. A postagem original tem duas perguntas: 1) por que o trema foi removido? e 2) há algum benefício? A consequência de sua postagem não oferecer resposta a nenhuma delas (embora implique não haver vantagem nenhuma) é ela violar o formato do site e assim poder vir a ser removida.