# Quais são os fonemas usados na língua portuguesa?

Tags: fonemas, definição

Fonemas são unidades sonoras que uma língua estabelece, entretanto, uma mesma letra pode produzir vários fonemas diferentes e um mesmo fonema pode ser representado por várias letras diferentes (um relacionamento muitos-para-muitos).

Entretanto, eu nunca soube que fonemas correspondem a quais letras, dependendo da situação em que essa letra é usada. Como por exemplo a letra `f` ser representada por `/f/`.

Procurando sobre [fonema na Wikipedia em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme), pode-se ver que existem outros fonemas que nem sequer são representados na nossa língua, como por exemplo `/niːm/` em `/ˈfoʊniːm/`, que é a maneira correta de se pronunciar `phoneme` em inglês.

Portanto, eu gostaria de saber quais são os fonemas que a língua portuguesa usa, assim como o som que eles produzem.

Comment: Bem complicada esta @Math

Comment: Pois é, eu estava tentando melhorar uma resposta minha mas eu não estou conseguindo por falta de conhecimento em fonemas. Será muito útil para mim e também acredito que muita gente poderá aprender bastante com uma resposta bem elaborada.

Comment: Já leste o artigo sobre a [Fonologia da língua portuguesa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa)?

Comment: Eu gosto do aspecto linguístico desta pergunta, o que aumenta o nível de perguntas neste site. Entretanto, me parece que é uma pergunta demasiado ampla e requer um artigo inteiro para ser respondida (se não um livro).

Comment: @OtavioMacedo o problema é que eu realmente não sei sobre fonemas, então qualquer luz já me ajudaria. Eu também fiquei preocupado em ser amplo demais, mas como eu não sei nada eu não consigo deixar o escopo dela mais fechado. O estilo dela me lembra um pouco [essa pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/148/3) que chegou a ser votada para fechar, mas depois viram que era possível responder. Se você souber como deixar minha pergunta mais "respondível" pode me falar, por que eu estou quase que totalmente no escuro mesmo :)

Comment: É importante saber que um fonema não é simplesmente um "som", mas um som que causa distinção de *sentido* (variações de som sem variação de sentido são chamados de *alofones*).

Comment: Meu Deus! Como eu sou ignorante em português e não sabia! Muitas informações novas para um único dia.

Comment: @tchrist não tinha visto, isso me parece muito útil, obrigado

Comment: Math, considerando seus novos aprendizados (rs), será que você quer mesmo saber sobre *fonemas* / fonologia, ou sobre os sons da língua / fonética?

Comment: @bfavaretto prometo ver isso com mais calma amanhã (sim, no sábado), ainda não cheguei a uma conclusão. Apareça por aqui que trocamos umas ideias :)

Comment: @Math sugiro que você dê começe comece com [esta pergunta, linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/180/whats-the-difference-between-phonetics-and-phonology), sobre a diferença entre fonologia e fonética.

Comment: @OtavioMacedo vou ler sim, obrigado pelo link

Comment: @bfavaretto pelo que entendi [desse link](https://ericasitta.wordpress.com/2012/07/07/qual-e-a-diferenca-entre-fonetica-e-fonologia/) e do link do Otavio, eu quero saber sobre a fonética

Comment: @bfavaretto e Math: Parece-me que um de vocês os dois ou ambos os dois é que poderão saber responder melhor a [esta pergunta de um membro novo](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/por-que-fonemas-n%C3%A3o-s%C3%A3o-%C3%BAnicos). Nós ainda não temos aqui no site uma explicação simples do que é um fonema. Eu pensava que sabia, e agora já estou mais inseguro.

Answer (score 7):

Na Wikipédia há um artigo  extenso sobre isso: [IPA for Portuguese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Portuguese)

A tabela indica também os diferentes fonemas para pt-PT e pt-BR.

## Cuidado

- Parecem faltar alguns casos de uso, por exemplo o x de sexta-feira;
- <del>Parece ter erros, por exemplo em pt-PT "pente, pequeno, se" lêm-se com `/e/` e não com `/ɨ/`</del>.

## Tabela com os IPA e as suas pronúncias

Este site tem tabelas com os códigos IPA, que são clicáveis para ouvir o seu som respectivo: http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/

Comment: @ANeves The IPA is about _phonetics_. The OP is asking about _phonology/phonemics_.

Comment: @JorgeB. `/ɨ/` é uma representação tradicional do "e" final no pt-PT ([vogel posterior fechada não arredondada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vogal_posterior_fechada_n%C3%A3o_arredondada), representada em IPA internacional com `/ɯ/`). É bem diferente do `ê`, representada com `/e/` e o `é`, representada com `/ɛ/`.

Comment: @DanGetz agora teria de ouvir para ter a certeza. É porque, por exemplo, "pequeno" diz-se "piqueno", mas na dia-a-dia toda a gente diz "pequeno". Já estou com uma confusão na minha cabeça...

Comment: @JorgeB. é a diferença entre ortografia, fonologia, e fonética. Há letras, fonemas, e sons, e não sempre corresponde de forma igual. A letra "e" em português tem muitos sons.

Comment: Hey, @DanGetz ou @ Earthliŋ, não querem melhorar a resposta ou criar uma alternativa bem feita?

Comment: Quando eu criei a pergunta eu achei que eu queria saber sobre fonema, quando na verdade nesse momento estou quase certo que eu queria saber era sobre fonética. Apesar de eu ter me expressado mal você conseguiu captar qual foi a minha intenção. Esse link me parece muito bom, apesar dos probleminhas que você citou.

Answer (score 1):

No português Europeu:

[14 fonemas para vogais](https://european-portuguese.info/vowels): á, é, i, ó, u, â, ê, ô, ã, ẽ, im, õ, um, e ainda o E mudo.

[19 fonemas para as consoantes](https://european-portuguese.info/): b, d, k, f, g, j, l, lh, m, n, nh, p, rr, r, s, t, v, x, z.