# O que é um fonema? Por que razão um fonema não é um som único?

Tags: fonemas

Estou estudando por conta própria e sempre vejo a definição de fonema como "a menor unidade sonora distintiva". Por que não única? Se ao trocar um fonema gera distinção entre as palavras, deve-se à unicidade do fonema trocado, certo?

Comment: Não sei se isto responderá à tua questão, mas lá vai. Dirias também que a sílaba é única? Se eu pegar em *gato* e trocar *ro* por *ga* gera outra palavra distinta: *roto*. Mas a sílaba não é a menor unidade. Se eu trocar só o **r**, que é uma unidade menor que a sílaba, por **g** também gero uma palavra distinta: *rato*. Portanto, ser único não chega para definir um fonema. Eu achei [as respostas a esta pergunta](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/180/whats-the-difference-between-phonetics-and-phonology), em especial a do evpok, muito úteis para perceber o que é um fonema.

Comment: @Anderson: Vejo que és novo no site. Boas vindas (ainda que atrasadas). Não sei se o meu comentário acima respondeu à tua dúvida? Se quiseres deixar feedback, é só clicar no "Add comment abaixo" e dizeres de tua justiça.

Comment: @Jacinto, obrigado pela resposta. Ajudou a me direcionar para a solução.  Sim, sou novo aqui, conheci esse site hoje. Não sabia que havia uma parte dedicada somente para linguística. Caso tenha postado na parte errada, desculpe. E sim, seu comentário foi útil e do evpok também. Se eu entendi correto, basicamente não podemos considerar única pois existem variações na pronúncia que representam o mesmo fonema (como ele usou no exemplo do _ring_). Obrigado pela ajuda! :)

Comment: @Anderbeserk A pergunta é perfeitamente apropriada para o SE.Portuguese Language. O que não te impede de a colocar no Linguistics também (mas é melhor antes ver se já lá há perguntas semelhantes com respostas que te satisfaçam), Eu não conheço o Linguistics. Fui lá parar através [desta pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/447/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-fonemas-usados-na-l%C3%ADngua-portuguesa).

Comment: É uma boa pergunta. Espero que receba respostas de qualidade. :)

Comment: @Jacinto: seu comentário responde a pergunta, acho que deveria constar como resposta.

Comment: @DenisCaixeta: Obrigado pelo voto de confiança. Segui o teu conselho.

Comment: @Anderberserk Vê a edição que eu fiz do teu título. Se não estiveres de acordo, é só voltares a pôr como estava. Eu acho que a pergunta fica mais clara assim.

Comment: @Jacinto Desculpa a demora, vi e ficou bem melhor assim. A forma antiga não estava muito clara.

Comment: Eh pá, é mesmo assim. Às vezes uma pessoa tem que andar às voltas até atinar com uma forma clara de exprimir as suas ideias.

Answer (score 8):

O fonema é a menor unidade sonora distintiva. Esta definição envolve uma porção de coisas. Portanto vamos por partes.

Primeiro, um fonema é uma unidade sonora e não uma letra. Por exemplo a letra **o** corresponde ao fonema /ɔ/ em *f**o**ca* e ao fonema /u/ em *c**o**mer*. O fonema /u/ é realizado pela letra **o** em *c**o**mer* e pela letra **u** em *fr**u**ta*. O **x** é uma letra de uma promiscuidade atroz: realiza o fonema /ʃ/ em *bai**x**o*, /s/ em *má**x**imo*, /z/ em *e**x**ato* e os dois fonemas /ks/ juntos em *fi**x**o*. O fonema /s/ não lhe fica atrás: é realizado pela letra **s** em *can**s**ado* por um **s** duplo em *ma**ss**a*, por **x** em *má**x**imo* e por **ç** em *ca**ç**a*.

Segundo, qualquer fonema é distinto de todos os outros. Portanto se numa palavra substituirmos um fonema por outro, obteremos uma palavra diferente da primeira. Por exemplo, a palavra *gato* é constituída por quatro fonemas: /g/, /a/, /t/ e /u/. Se substituirmos o fonema /g/ pelo fonema /p/ obtemos uma palavra diferente: /patu/, escrita *pato*.

Então porque não dizemos pura e simplesmente que o fonema é um som único? Porque não é. Vejamos o exemplo da palavra *gago*. No português brasileiro ambos os guês têm o mesmo som: [g]. Mas no português europeu têm sons diferentes: o primeiro é igual ao do Brasil, mas o segundo é mais suave, representando-se por [ɣ]. Cada um destes sons, [g] e [ɣ], é único. A sons únicos chamamos *fones* (e representamo-los entre parenteses retos, [ ], enquanto os fonemas são representados entre barras, //).

Ora o que acontece é que o falante nativo do português, a menos que esteja muito atento a estes fenómeno, nem sequer se apercebe da diferença entre [g] e [ɣ]. Ou seja, estes dois fones não são distintivos: se numa palavra substituirmos o fone [g] pelo [ɣ] ou vice-versa, continuamos a ter a mesma palavra. Por isso estes dois fones fazem parte do mesmo fonema, que representamos por /g/. Aos fones que fazem parte de um mesmo fonema chamamos *alofones*. Portanto um fonema pode não corresponder a um fone único, tal como o /g/ que compreende dois alofones.

No português brasileiro um fonema que compreende vários alofones é o /ʀ/, como em *mel**r**o*, que tem sons ligeiramente diferentes consoante a região do país. Mas passa-se o mesmo que como o /g/ e o [ɣ]: se numa palavra, apenas se substituir um dos alofones do /ʀ/ por outro alofone do /ʀ/, o falante nativo do português, mesmo que note alguma diferença vai continuar a entender a mesma palavra.

Por isso, os fones são unidades sonoras únicas e menores que o fonema (porque alguns fonemas incluem vários fones). Mas os fones de um mesmo fonema não são distintivos. Logo o fonema é a menor unidade sonora distintiva. Se dois ou mais fones fazem parte do mesmo fonema ou de fonemas diferentes pode variar língua para língua. Por exemplo, os sons [t] como em *ga**t**o* e [d] como em *ga**d**o* são distintos no português, logo correspondem a fonemas diferentes: /t/ e /d/. Mas [aos ouvidos dos coreanos estes sons são iguais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme#Minimal_pairs), na língua coreana são alofones do mesmo fonema. Existe uma palavra coreana com o som [tada]: portugueses e brasileiros distinguiriam os dois sons consoantes, mas os coreanos não os distinguem.

Isto foi apenas a introdução ao *fonema* que eu fui capaz de fazer. Mas isto é um mundo. Quem quiser aprofundar, possíveis pontos de partidas poderão ser os artigos na Wikipédia sobre [o fonema](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonema) ou sobre [fonologia da língua portuguesa.](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa)